# Genymotion unable to start the virtual device

Tags: android, genymotion

So basically I am a newbie to android development. All was working well till few days back I suddenly got error while starting my virtual device from genymotion. It is giving me this error:

> **Unable to start the virtual device**
>
> **The virtual device got no IP address.**

I have use following solutions to resolve my problem:

1. Edit the Host-only Network by clicking. Check that the adapter IPv4 address is in the same network (192.168.56.0/24 by default) as the DHCP server address, lower address bound and upper address bound.
2. Recreated the adapter with proper settings (as in step 1)
3. Reinstall the genymotion and virtualBox

But none of the above mentioned steps worked for me, and it is quite frutsrating as I can't spend any more time on this issue. So, is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe some errors are related to the amount of Base Memory that we put in VirtualBox, on some systems should lower it to 1GB, not to collapse the connection between the emulator program (Genymotion) and the virtual machine.

Sorry for my english but it's not my native language ;)

see if this helps you

http://goo.gl/caE3pF

Answer (score 0):

So,what i did to solve my problem was that i uninstalled both virtualBox and genymotion and upgraded my virtualbox to 4.3 version and again installed both virtualBox and genymotion.After completing all the installations genymotion is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error even when DHCP settings was proper. Figured out finally that there was a mismatch between my host config and the VM settings for the virtual device(mine was 64 bit, while VM was 32 bit). Got it working by setting the VM to 64 bit.(right click on VM image on VirtualBox-->Settings-->General-->Version)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too awhile ago. But, none of this answer can fix it.

For my problem, I fix it by trying to run the vm on Virtual Box then I got the error message. It said **VT-x is disabled by Bios**, so I open the vm settings on virtual box, in **System** -> **Acceleration** -> **Uncheck VT-x/AMD-V**

After that, I can run the virtual device normally

Answer (score 0):

If your Acceleration Tab is grayed out, you can enable it in the BIOS setting. Find out the option (Internet) Virtualization Technology and Enable it.

For ASUS, it is under CPU Configuration; For HP Laptop, it is under System configurations>Device Configurations> Virtualization Technology.

After Enabling it, you can restart your computer and check it. If still doesn't work, please completely shut down the PC and then start it.

For more detailed demo please refer to the video: [How to enable Grayed Out Acceleration tab in VirtualBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hblea5KHFkk)

Then you can go on the settings as Raiz-al shared above.