# Genymotion showing blank window

Tags: android, genymotion

When I open virtual device in genymotion why does window remain blank??

even tried every possible solution. I changed IPv4 Adresses and IPv4 network mask

but I am not able to solve any suggestions please??

Comment: chek this ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164415/virtual-device-of-genymotion-statred-but-displaying-white-screen?rq=1

Comment: did you solve problem by updating graphics driver??

Comment: first try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210823/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-virtual-device?rq=1

Comment: it does not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please update your graphics card driver to the latest one
 [link](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/)

then try to start the virtual device again.